# NHD Flowline legend colors?

Tags: legend, color, united-states, standards, usgs

Does Anyone have legend colors for the NHD Flowline that USGS sets colors for theirs ?

I'd like to get a copy of their color legend.

They can be from their website, brouchure, lyr files or anything that I can set it up easily to match their colors.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the symbology you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [USGS/FGDC document](http://ngmdb.usgs.gov/fgdc_gds/geolsymstd/fgdc-geolsym-all.pdf), found [here](http://ngmdb.usgs.gov/fgdc_gds/geolsymstd/download.php), has some info on stream data symbology (page A-30).

Comment: For just water http://ngmdb.usgs.gov/fgdc_gds/geolsymstd/fgdc-geolsym-sec30.pdf